# Build console app with different assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console app. I want to use this console app as the shell for multiple console apps. The "brains" of each app are in a separate assembly. My question is, is there a way for me to pass in which assembly I want to use at build time and the output name I want to use for the .exe file?

For example, I have the following three .NET Core projects in separate solutions, in three separate .git repositories

1. MyConsoleShell (this is a console app)
2. MyFirstApp (this is an assembly)
3. MySecondApp (this is an assembly)

I would like run two builds such that MyConsoleShell is the shell console for: MyFirstApp.exe and MySecondApp.exe. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is there a way? If so, how?

Comment: "Shell console" and "brains" are informal terms that do not communicate a specific architecture. Can you maybe provide an example of how you would like it to work? How does the console app know how to use one of its "brains"? Do they have the exact same types and methods? Are you using a common interface?

Comment: @JohnWu They have the exact same types and methods. There's a common interface in place.

Comment: Visual Studio projects can be referenced in multiple solutions. Can you add MyConsoleShell as an exiting project both  MyFirstApp and MySecondApp solutions?

Comment: @mje777 I don't see a way to do that. I know in Node, there's a way to reference repositories by URL. However, I don't see a way to do that in Visual Studio. The only approach I see at the moment would require me copying `MyConsoleShell` code in both places. That seems hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use a plugin architecture for doing this. 
I mean, you can start your consoleApp with config or commandline parameter which will specify what exactly will run.
There is a library for managing plugins in .NETCore: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/25/netcore-plugins/